# Receiver of Upload Button Vaadin

Tags: file-upload, vaadin, vaadin7, receiver

I am trying to upload a file. It uploads fine, but while uploading it shows all file. I want to restrict to only selected files like `pdf,jpg` and `jpeg` files.

I need to while uploading a file when a browser window open that time only these files are visible remaining file should be hide. So that user is not able to select wrong file.

Can anyone tell me how can I do this?

I am using Vaadin 7.5.1 and Upload component and a Receiver.

Comment: Unfortunally webbrowser don't have this possiblity. It's not a restriction of vaadin.

Comment: @AndréSchild. Really? I believe all major browsers support this. IE was kind of late to the party but this is now all history. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36482062/1504556)

Comment: @peterh Ohh... interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The current [Vaadin Upload component](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-upload.html) does not support this. There's an [enhancement request](https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/8857) for it which would be dead easy for Vaadin Inc (or a contributor) to implement now that all the major browsers support this functionality.

Here's the technical explanation: The Vaadin Upload component creates HTML like this:

```
<input type="file" name="foo">
```

but what you would have liked it to produce would be something like this:

```
<input type="file" name="foo" accept=".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg">
```

Here's how the above HTML will look in Firefox:

[image]

Basically the `accept` attribute will tell the browser to open a file selection dialog with a certain filter.

Note that this is a client-side thing. It doesn't prevent a savvy end user from uploading something that doesn't match your filter to your server. That  goes for any kind of filtering done on the client-side no matter how it is done. For this reason you'll still need some server-side validation as well.

Comment: Html "accept" does not limit file types for upload, it simply adds soft filter to file choose dialog, so user can switch filter to All files and upload file with another extension in this case.

Comment: True. You'll still need some server side validation as well to be certain, but I believe OP was asking for the client side user experience of having a (default) filter in the file selection window.

Answer (score 1):

Piece of cake with JavaScript - you just have to check into the HTML source of page where that button/browse field is placed to find actuall class name of generated html element - this is example for .csv, Vaadin generates class name titled "gwt-FileUpload", so you have to set it like this to see only .csv files after clicking on "Import" button:

```
upload.setButtonCaption("Import");
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("document.getElementsByClassName('gwt-FileUpload')[0].setAttribute('accept', '.csv')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency to your pom file

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.wcs.wcslib</groupId>
   <artifactId>wcslib-vaadin-widget-multifileupload</artifactId>
   <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

And use the following code to upload files, set filter using `setAcceptFilter` method:

```
UploadStateWindow uploadStateWindow = new UploadStateWindow();
        uploadStateWindow.setOverallProgressVisible(true);
MultiFileUpload fileUpload = new MultiFileUpload(uploadFinishedHandler,
                uploadStateWindow, true);
fileUpload.setAcceptFilter(".png,.jpg");
fileUpload.setImmediate(true);

fileUpload.getSmartUpload().setUploadButtonCaptions("upload", "upload");
```